# Wordpress Pagination different post limits on different pages

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I hope I can explain my problem correctly.

In my custom theme I have tried to understand and implement pagination (that little numbered buttons on the bottom to show the next/previous x posts).

For that, I started of with a copy/pasted code snippet from [this site here](http://www.wpexplorer.com/pagination-wordpress-theme/) for trying to understand the mechanics behind it.

```
<?php
if ( !function_exists( 'wpex_pagination' ) ) {
function wpex_pagination() {

    $prev_arrow = is_rtl() ? '&rarr;' : '&larr;';
    $next_arrow = is_rtl() ? '&larr;' : '&rarr;';

    global $wp_query;
    $total = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
    $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
    if( $total > 1 )  {
         if( !$current_page = get_query_var('paged') )
             $current_page = 1;
         if( get_option('permalink_structure') ) {
             $format = 'page/%#%/';
         } else {
             $format = '&paged=%#%';
         }
        echo paginate_links(array(
            'base'          => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
            'format'        => $format,
            'current'       => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
            'total'         => $total,
            'mid_size'      => 3,
            'type'          => 'list',
            'prev_text'     => $prev_arrow,
            'next_text'     => $next_arrow,
         ) );
    }
}
```

}

This works quite well and is also easy to understand. So I wonder, if I can change **max_num_pages** on the following pages, so I can say display 5 posts on the first and 10 posts on following pages. (Text before the posts is just shown on the first page, so I have more Space on the following pages).

I tried with

```
$pageNumOffset = 5;
$temp = 0;
if(! is_page( 'ratgeber' )){
   $temp = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
   $total = $temp + $pageNumOffset;
}
```

and vice versa (if is_page, else), but neither of these seems to work.  And the  if statement never triggers.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I have done a version of both offsets over on [wordpress.se] and I think I did repost it here. It basically uses `pre_get_posts` to alter the main query accordingly. Feel free to search my posts here and over at WPSE

Comment: How could I have not thought about searching stack exchange for a wordpress themed channel... Am going to check yout posts out now and ask further questions there. thank you, Pieter!